# Using send_file in helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use `send_file` method in application_helper.rb and receiving the following error:

```
undefined method `send_file' for #<#<Class:0x00000003cc7ad8>:0x00000003cc4ea0>
```

Is there a way to get around this? I know that I can put my helper inside controller but I don't want to do that.

Comment: Few years later, and what you have used instead to render image using helper? (As I can't use controller,in my specific case :/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use send_file inside your helper.

Explain, why do you need to send file from your view helper and how should it work?

Comment: I have a helper that shows a featured image for a record. In case that record doesn't have a featured image it sends the default image with 404 status. Sort of like Paperclip works.

Comment: you problem that you don't need to use send_file for this :)

Comment: probably, i just realized it too :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't send a file from a helper.

The [send_file](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html#method-i-send_file) method is defined in ActionController::Streaming and is therefore not available in helpers. Helpers are for your code which helps with views. If you're writing a 'helper' for a controller, it shouldn't really be a helper. It should be a module in lib which you require and include in the controller.